# NGINX Incorrectly Forwarding Requests to Default Location

Tags: nginx, https

I have a React web application that I'm trying to deploy on an AWS EC2 instance and I'm using NGINX. I am trying to set it up so that all http requests get redirected to https. Right now it does appear to be redirecting all http requests to https, but NGINX is forwarding the request to the default path /usr/share/nginx/html/ instead of to the web application that I have running on localhost. I have read dozens of articles and have been trying to figure this out for days. Pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my NGINX server configuration at /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:

```
server {

  listen 80;

  if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}

server {

  listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
  listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
  ssl_session_timeout 1h;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3839;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  }
}
```

Also, the application is running and accessible at the port specified in my location block. I can reach it on the machine with curl 127.0.0.1:3839 with no problems. I am able to see in /var/log/nginx/error.log that nginx is attempting to serve requests out of the /usr/share/nginx/html/ directory which is how I figured out that is the issue. I just have no idea why it's sending requests there instead of to the port on localhost that I specified in my location block. If I go to the root url for my application I get the "Welcome to NGINX" page. If I go to any subpath under my root url like example.com/login, then I get a 404 and error.log shows that it couldn't find resource /usr/share/nginx/html/login for example. Thanks :)

Update:

Inside of the listen 80 server block I added

```
location / { 
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3839; 
}
```

and now it seems to be working correctly, but I have no idea why I would need to define a location block in the listen 80 server definition if requests in that block are just being redirected to be caught by the other server definition listening on 443. Any idea why this is working now?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason that location block in the http server definition worked. In AWS I accidentally had my load balancer forwarding all requests to port 80 on the EC2 instance. So even though my http server definition was redirecting to the https version of the site, those https requests were still ending up being handled by that same http server definition and since it didn't have a location block at all previously, that was causing it to fail. In the end, I removed the location block from the http server definition and then correctly updated my load balancer to forward https requests to port 443 on the EC2 instance and now everything works as expected.